# CSS: When I change a background-image url() it no longer respects background-size: contain until I resize h&w

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am developing an interface for editing tiles in a Smart Home panel: https://github.com/open-dash/HousePanel

While editing a tile, users will be able to change the background-image of the tile from a library of icons. That is all working, except that when the image is replaced it ignores the background-size: cover for the element in CSS. However, if I change both the height and width it resizes correctly, and I can even set it back to the original size and it stays the right size (see image below.)

[Interface - User selects new image in step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2RfX.jpg)

Because the image is getting replaced, I tried setting the css after the fact, so, in this order:

```
background-image: url("http://192.168.1.1/icons/toilet.png");
background-size: contain;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
```

...but still I have to change the width and height of the parent div to have it reacalculate/contain to fill the parent div correctly. What gives?

Note: The above are all added via the following code snippet, which works fine otherwise, and I can see the changes when I inspect the element in chrome:

```
if(sheet.insertRule){
  if(index > -1) {
    sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);        
  }
  else{
    sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}");           
  }
}
else{
  if(index > -1) {
    sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);    
  }
  else{
    sheet.addRule(selector, rules);   
  }
}
```

Any thoughts? Is there any way to force it to recalculate the area it needs to fill?

TIA!

Comment: _"except that when the image is replaced"_ - show us where that happens! Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Well, I can't duplicate the issue in jsfiddle. I think the issue is the pecking order of CSS not being followed; Inspecting the element after I change the image I can see that it is using the dimensions of the less-specific class, and doesn't 'fix itself' until I bump the height and width a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct an on-the-fly stylesheet is created and xhr'd each time?

Have you tried to set the css property directly via jQuery? ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/x8naaxbq/))

If not, consider triggering a refresh of the element:

```
document.getElementById(selector).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(selector).style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: hmm, maybe that's the issue; I'm changing element's class properties (in the sheet loaded in memory) and not the named element it applies to. Works for things like color etc. but maybe not this.